# Determining for which parameter values a set: spans a vector space, is linearly independent, a base for a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let $V = \mathbb{R}^{3}$

and $v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1\\ a\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$, $v_2 = \begin{bmatrix}1\\ a+1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$, $v_3 = \begin{bmatrix}3\\ a+2\\ 3\end{bmatrix}$ $a\in \mathbb{R}$

Let $S = \left \{ v_1, v_2, v_3 \right \}$

For which $a\in \mathbb{R}$ :

$S$ spans $V$

$S$ is linearly independent

$S$ is a base for $V$.

So here's how I look at it: I can immidiately tell that $v_1, v_2$ are linearly independent, because each one of their coordinates is the same except for the middle one, and the equation $a = a+1$ has no solution -  therefore for each $a\in \mathbb{R}$ $v_1$ will no be equal to $v_2$.

I run the same procces between $v_1$ and $v_3$ and between $v_2$ and $v_3$ and I find out that they're linearly independent when $a \neq 1, \frac{1}{2}$

Since I found that these 3 vectors are linearly independent for $a \neq 1, \frac{1}{2}$ I know that $S$ is a base for $V$,  because $\left | S \right | = dimV$

And therfore $S$ ofcourse spans $V$ for these values.

However, this is an easy case of "look and understand" (Assuming that I got it right)..

I would like to to get a more direct and general approach to attack this kind of question. thank you!

Comment: Pairwise linear independence of $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$, does not imply linear independence of $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$.

Comment: @pH74 Why? if $v_1$ and $v_2$ are always linearly independent?

Comment: Think about $\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$. They are pairwise linearly independent but do not span $\mathbb R^3$.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comments, it is not sufficient to check for pairwise linear independence to conclude linear independence of the set ($S$).

> and $v_1 = \begin{bmatrix}1\\ a\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$, $v_2 = \begin{bmatrix}1\\ a+1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$, $v_3 = \begin{bmatrix}3\\ a+2\\ 3\end{bmatrix}$ $a\in \mathbb{R}$

Note that for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$, you have:
$$(1+2a)\begin{bmatrix}1\\ a\\ 1\end{bmatrix}
+(2-2a)\begin{bmatrix}1\\ a+1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}3\\ a+2\\ 3\end{bmatrix}$$
which means that $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$ are always linearly dependent.

> I would like to to get a more direct and general approach to attack this kind of question. thank you!

For three vectors in $\mathbb{R^3}$, a handy equivalent property uses the determinant: the matrix formed by the three vectors has a *non-zero determinant*  **if and only if** the vectors are *linearly independent*.

You can easily verify that for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$ (the first and last rows are identical):
$$\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 3 \\
a & a+1 & a+2 \\
1 & 1 & 3
\end{vmatrix}=0$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Let be $M\in\mathbb R^{3\times3}$ the matrix with columns $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$. $S$ is linearly independent if and only if $M$ has full rank. The row rank of $M$ is obvious.